# Why Estimote beacon is not detecting on Android?

Tags: android, beacon, estimote

I am working on Estimote beacon using estimote sdk, i have added both APP_ID and APP_TOKEN but still it's not able to detect.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  beaconManager = new com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());

  EstimoteSDK.initialize(getApplicationContext(), Constants.APP_ID, Constants.APP_TOKEN);

   beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
     @Override
     public void onEnteredRegion(com.estimote.sdk.Region region, java.util.List<com.estimote.sdk.Beacon> list) {
          showNotification("Welcome to the shop", "You are in");
     }

     @Override
     public void onExitedRegion(com.estimote.sdk.Region region) {

     }
  });
}
```

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

**Solution**

```
beaconManager.setNearableListener(new BeaconManager.NearableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNearablesDiscovered(java.util.List<com.estimote.sdk.Nearable> nearables) {

        }
    });

    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            scanId = beaconManager.startNearableDiscovery();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this sample http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-3-ranging-beacons/

Comment: @Lingeshwaran hey thanks i have tried this want but in their UUID is hardcoded but i want dynamically detect, can you please tell me how to detect these beacons dynamically ??

Comment: you dont have UUID ?

Comment: yes i have but it should be dynamic right, as per the example it will detect to that particular beacon only always.

Comment: you can hardcode your UUID but major number and minor number you should get only through programmatically.

Comment: On which version of Android you are testing ?

Comment: Check everyone i have go the solution

Comment: Now it is working?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran yes can you please up vote my post, because i have also posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using UUID and minor major that needs to be monitor :

```
    // this is were we left off:
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());
   // add this below:
   beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
   @Override
    public void onServiceReady() {
      beaconManager.startMonitoring(new BeaconRegion(
            "monitored region",
            UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"),
            22504, 48827));
    }
   });
```